# JavaScript conditional fields with radio does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a form with Bootstrap (jQuery) using a small script given a condition (selection on a radio button) one or the other elements are displayed.

It isn't working for me, there are no errors in the debugger but it performs the action.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="typeStorage" id="typeStorageRemote" value="typeStorageRemote" checked>
            Recommended option. Backup stored on remote server using rsync + ssh
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
//On original value was wrong. I (same value on all radio)
            <input type="radio" name="typeStorage" id="typeStorageLocal" value="typeStorageLocal">
            Options not recommended. Backup stored in device mounted locally
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- All components tabs storage -->
<!-- Option Remote -->
<div class="form-group" id="groupRemote">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="storageServer" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Server (Hostname or Ip)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="storageServer" placeholder="Server">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="storagePort" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Server port</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="storagePort" placeholder="Port">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Option local -->
<div class="form-group hidden" id="groupLocal">
    <label for="storageLocal" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Local path</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="storageLocal" placeholder="Local">
    </div>
</div>
```

Script loaded after jquery.js`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var typeStorage = $('#formSettings input:radio[name=typeStorage]');
    // Wrappers
    var inRemote = $('#formSettings #groupRemote');
    var inHome   = $('#formSettings #groupLocal');
    var all      = inRemote.add(inHome); // shortcuts

    typeStorage.change( function() {
        var value=this.value;
        all.addClass('hidden'); // hide all and show when need
        if (value == 'typeStorageRemote') {
            inRemote.removeClass('hidden'); // show grup groupRemote
        } else {
            inHome.removeClass('hidden'); // show grup groupLocal
        }
    });
});
```

Develop URL (deactivate all routes) http://dashboard.cprsync.com/settings

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: just FYI both your radio buttons have the same value so in your javascript the `if` will always be true

Comment: please post the exact error

Comment: deppem is right. its just the duplicated radio value that keeps that hing from working

Comment: Edit comment.. I see my obtuse error... too many hours...

Comment: Not good work long hours ... thanks @depperm

Comment: Thanks Tiny Giant for correct my poor english. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to have non-unique `id` attributes on a page.  Also, as mentioned in the comments by **depperm** and **Stefan Dochow**, the name variable should be unique too.

Answer (score 0):

Failed to assign the same value (for error) the two radio buttons. Once everyone has their own id and your own value, it works perfectly.

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="typeStorage" id="typeStorageRemote" value="typeStorageRemote" checked>
        Recommended option. Backup stored on remote server using rsync + ssh
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
//On original value was wrong. I (same value on all radio)
        <input type="radio" name="typeStorage" id="typeStorageLocal" value="typeStorageLocal">
        Options not recommended. Backup stored in device mounted locally
    </label>
</div>
```